# get mybatis query response time

Tags: mybatis

Is there a way we can get query response time for queries run using myBatis. I am using myBatis xml query way.

I did try turning on TRACE logging for myBatis, but seems like it does not log response time as part of it.

Other way I could think of is using an interceptor.

Is there any out of the box solution provided ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use log4j, for example:

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Console  

#Console  
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p [%c] - %m%n  

log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=INFO  
log4j.logger.org.apache=INFO  
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG  
log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG  
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG
```

mybatis-config.xml:

```
<settings>   
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
</settings>
```

[image]